# Upload multiple photos to SFTP in Async

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ftp, sftp

I want to upload multiple photos to `SFTP server` but with the following code only one photo is uploaded. Please anybody has any idea where I m getting wrong or have a better approach for this

```
private class uploadFileOnFTPServerAsync extends
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pdDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            pdDialog = new ProgressDialog(MediaFileAttachmentActivity.this);
            pdDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait..");
            pdDialog.show();
            pdDialog.setCancelable(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (mediaDataList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mediaDataList.size(); i++) {
                if (mediaDataList.get(i).getMediaFTPPath()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("")) {                
                        uploadFileonSFTP(mediaDataList.get(i)
                                .getmFile(), mediaDataList.get(i)
                                .getMediaName(), "images");
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdDialog.dismiss();
        MediaFileAttachmentActivity.this.finish();
        Toast.makeText(MediaFileAttachmentActivity.this,
                "Attachments saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}

  private void uploadFileonSFTP(final File file2, String app_filename,
        String type){
    try{

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                connectToSFTP(file2);

            }
        }).start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}


 private void connectToSFTP(File file2) 
 {

    try {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        session = jsch.getSession(USER_NAME,SERVER_ADDRESS,PORT_NO);

        session.setPassword(AppSingleton.getInstance().getPASSWORD());

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();

        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");

        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        channelSftp.cd(AppSingleton.getInstance().getPATH());
        //  File f = new File(file2);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(file2), file2.getName());

        session.disconnect();

        channel.disconnect();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating a thread instead of Asynctask

private void executeThread() 
{

```
    final ProgressDialog pdDialog;
    pdDialog = new ProgressDialog(MediaFileAttachmentActivity.this);
                    pdDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait..");
                    pdDialog.show();
                    pdDialog.setCancelable(false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mediaDataList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mediaDataList.size(); i++) {
                    if (mediaDataList.get(i).getMediaFTPPath()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                            uploadFileonSFTP(mediaDataList.get(i)
                                    .getmFile(), mediaDataList.get(i)
                                    .getMediaName(), "images");

                    }
                }
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pdDialog.dismiss();
                    MediaFileAttachmentActivity.this.finish();
                    Toast.makeText(MediaFileAttachmentActivity.this,
                            "Attachments saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}
```